# Creating selectable icons in form

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using an icon font on my website and I want users to vote on their favorite icon. the icon font uses  and CSS to display the icon.  How can I accomplish this using some type of jQuery and returning the icon to the front end along with passing it value through a form?

I know I can't add a  inside of an  input, so i took this approach:

I started with this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6NVpL/42/

HTML:

```
 <div class="iconDisplay">Display's selected icon</div>

 <button class="selectIcon">Select Icon</button>

 <div id="iconSelector">
     <span class="icon-icon1"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon2"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon3"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon4"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon5"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon6"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon7"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon8"></span>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
 $(".selectIcon").click(function () {
   $("#iconSelector").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#iconSelector span").click(function () {
    $(this).click(function(){
        $("#iconSelector").hide();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/) is more what you are looking for?

I fixed the click handlers:

```
$("#selectIconButton").click(function () {
    $("#iconSelector").fadeToggle();
});

$("#iconSelector span").click(function () {
    selectIcon($(this));
});
```

Added a function to perform the icon selection. Note: remove the `return;` statement and adjust the post so it will work for your application.

```
function selectIcon(e){
    var selection = e.attr('class');
    $('#selectedIcon')
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(selection)
        .show();
    $("#iconSelector").hide();
    return;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'urltowebsite',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { selectedIcon: selection }
    });
}
```

Added a UI element to show the user what icon they selected and modified the CSS slightly to accommodate the above changes.

Comment: On the right track @Jay, Just that when you select a bunch at a time, it doesn't remove the previous class, therefore the selection just keeps on adding classes to the same #selectedIcon span

Comment: How can i remove the previous clicked class?

Comment: Glad I could help. I updated my answer with your corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server-side script to save the data. If you do have a script for that, you can use it like that:

```
$("#iconSelector span").click(function () {
    var xthis = $(this);
    xthis.click(function(){
        $("#iconSelector").hide();
        $.post('/echo/html','icon='+$(xthis).attr('class'),function(){
            $(".iconDisplay").html(xthis.get(0));
        });
    });
});
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6NVpL/45/

PS. Change `/echo/html` to your save script name.